# Issues replacing values within DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I need remove (?) from multiple cells in an excel sheet, to do this I entered the sheet into a data frame and went through replacing values that needed to be changed, however, when a value ended in a (?) [e.g. 'value(?)'] using df.replace I would get the error

```
df = df.replace(to_replace='gold (?)', value='gold', regex= True)

"error: unknown extension ?) at position 1"
```

So I tried:

```
df=df.replace(to_replace="(?)", value=' ', regex= True)
```

This yielded the same result. Any tips?

Comment: `(`, `?` and `)` have special meanings in `regex`.  When you set `regex=True` it will no longer be looking for the literal characters `(?)`.  Try removing `regex=True`.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be easier to do a Find and Replace in Excel instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df = df.replace('(?)', '')
```

Or if you want to use regex, escape special characters

```
df = df.replace('\s+\(\?\)', '', regex=True)
```